# How to evaluate JSON from JSON Schema

Tags: apache-nifi

I am familiar with using an .XSD to validate an .XML file using the processor ValidateXML in Apache NIFI.

How can I transform XML to JSON and then validate the outputted JSON with a JSON Schema that would produce the same results as the XSD validating the XML file?

Is there another tool that I can use with NIFI to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the conversion part, you could use [this XSLT](https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson) to transform the XML in to JSON via the [TransformXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html) processor.

A ValidateJson processor is in the works under [NIFI-1893](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1893), in the meantime you can use ExecuteScript with the approach in [this post](http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/05/validating-json-in-nifi-with.html), or use [ExecuteStreamCommand](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) with option #2 from [@Yaser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5335917/yaser-adel-mehraban)'s answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information @mattyb. Is there a good place to go for updates on new processors coming soon?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**:

There is an open source lib on [github](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler) which allows you to convert `XML schema` to `JSON`.

Let's say you have the XML schema like this:

```
<xsd:element name="purchaseOrder" type="PurchaseOrderType"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="shipTo" type="USAddress"/>
      <xsd:element name="billTo" type="USAddress"/>
      <xsd:element ref="comment" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="items"  type="Items"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="orderDate" type="xsd:date"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And the the conversion can be done by this command:

```
java -jar jsonix-schema-compiler-full.jar
     -generateJsonSchema
     -p PO
     schemas/purchaseorder.xsd
```

Then you can use the result to validate you JSON, however bare in mind that this is not a one to one mapping. You may need to tweak the result a bit.

**Solution #2**:

You can use this open source [lib](https://github.com/fnogatz/xsd2json) to do the same.

You can follow the instruction on the readme file but the usage to convert the same schema would be:

```
xsd2json /path/to/purchaseorder.xsd > /created/purchaseorder.json
```

Hope you this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Yaser Adel Mehraban, I am currently investigating Solution #2 to see if it implements the transformation with expected results.